# iOS Sqlite database is not showing first record

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

I want to fetch all records inserted into sqlite database: Favorite table.
I have wrote following code: to fetch all records from database.
 it gives me records but first record is not showing...

for ex: if table has 3 records
        it gives me only 2 records first record is missing.
 When I execute query using sqlite manager it shows me proper 3 records..

```
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
        NSString *sqlStatement = @"SELECT * FROM Favorite ;";
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
         NSLog(@"Database returned error %d: %s", sqlite3_errcode(database), sqlite3_errmsg(database));

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlStatement UTF8String], -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {

            NSLog(@"srow==%d",sqlite3_step(compiledStatement));

            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {


                // title
                NSString *fti=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,0)];

                NSString * ftitle = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",fti];
                [app.favdbTitle addObject:ftitle];
                NSLog(@"ttile==%@",ftitle);

                //desc
                NSString *fdes=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,1)];

                NSString * fdesc = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",fdes];
                [app.favdbDec addObject:fdesc];


                int favno=sqlite3_column_int(compiledStatement, 2);
                NSInteger fvno=favno;
                [app.favdbid addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)fvno]];

                //cat 1
                NSString *fca1=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,3)];

                NSString * fcate1 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",fca1];
                [app.favcat1 addObject:fcate1];

               //cat 2
                NSString *fca2=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,4)];

                NSString * fcate2 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",fca2];
                [app.favcat2 addObject:fcate2];

                //cat 2
                NSString *fca3=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement,5)];

                NSString * fcate3 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",fca3];
                [app.favcat3 addObject:fcate3];







            }

        }
        // Release the compiled statement from memory
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
```

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks , yes working on custom objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that, before your `while` loop, you have a `NSLog` that is calling `sqlite3_step`, too. Thus, this `NSLog` will retrieve the first record and the `while` loop will then pick up at the second record.

Just remove that `NSLog` with the `sqlite3_step` call and you should be fine.